# Python Locust - custom timeout in req/task

Tags: python, request, locust

I need to run some Load tests with Locust lib. I neeed to to handle 504-gateway timeout in specific way. Is there a possibility to put custom timeout in request (or maybe task). I do not need to wait 120 sec till timeout occurs, I need to wait not wait longer than 5 sec and for me it is timeout.
I mean in code:

```
@task(1)
def check_max_5_sec(self):
   self.client.get(url=URL_5_sec)

...

@task(1)
def check_max_10_sec(self):
   self.client.get(url=URL_10_sec)
```

In ideal world I'd like to see failures on Locust web interface if there is no response within given timeout.
How to achieve this?

I know that in `FastHttp` there is `connection_timeout`  and `network_timeout`  (probably this might be a solution), but can I do this with `HttpUser`?

Answer (score 0):

For HttpUser/requests just pass `timeout=5`.

See https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts for more info.

Comment: The simplest solution is the best solution. I've missed this param. Thank You